# jQuery - How to use a single function to set global variables to true by detecting div id clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to use a single function to detect which div was clicked and then set the corresponding variable to true.  So if I clicked ID "click1", then I would like to set VAR "click1_view" to true.

I'm having trouble getting the variable within the function to evaluate, what am I missing?  I'm fairly new to jQuery.  In action script it would have simply been eval(thisViewed) = true; but that does not work here.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="circle" id="click1">1</div>
<div class="circle" id="click2">2</div>
<div class="circle" id="click3">3</div>
<div class="circle" id="click4">4</div>
<div class="circle" id="click5">5</div>

<script>
     var click1_view = false;
     var click2_view = false;
     var click3_view = false;
     var click4_view = false;
     var click5_view = false;

     function showContent(){
          var thisBtn = $(this).attr('id');
          var thisViewed = thisBtn + "_view";

          thisViewed = true;

          console.log(click1_view);
     }

     $('#click1').click(showContent);
     $('#click2').click(showContent);
     $('#click3').click(showContent);
     $('#click4').click(showContent);
     $('#click5').click(showContent);
</script>
```

Comment: use an array rather than separated variables, and use the number as index

Comment: There are some better implementations here but if you insist on using dynamic variables, try `window[thisBtn+"_view"] = true;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a object to persist which element is viewed and [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to set the set property using variable.

Additionally as you have added a common class to element use it to attach event handlers

```js
var obj = {
  click1_view: false,
  click2_view: false,
  click3_view: false,
  click4_view: false,
  click5_view: false
}

function showContent() {
  var thisBtn = $(this).attr('id');
  var thisViewed = thisBtn + "_view";
  //Use bracket notation to set the property value
  obj[thisViewed] = true;
  console.clear();
  console.log(obj);
}

$('.circle').click(showContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle" id="click1">1</div>
<div class="circle" id="click2">2</div>
<div class="circle" id="click3">3</div>
<div class="circle" id="click4">4</div>
<div class="circle" id="click5">5</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Satpal!  This is much cleaner and works perfectly to solve my issue.  I'm still new with jQuery so I wouldn't have thought to use this approach, but now I'm able to follow this along perfectly.  I added a check in a completion function and now my page is completing properly!

Answer (score 0):

is it mandatory that you have to use `_view` in naming ? You could achieve this with a simple array

```
var clicked= = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= <yournumberOfVariables>; i++) {
  clicked[i] = false;
}

function showContent() {
  var thisBtn = $(this).attr('id');
  clicked[parseInt(thisViewed)] = true;
  console.clear();
  console.log(true); // you're printing thisViewed that is always true at this point
}
```

and to register your events

```
for (var i = 1; i <= <yournumberOfClicks>; i++) {
     $('#click' + i).click(showContent);
}
```

or better, use the class selector

```
$('.circle').click(showContent);
```

Comment: Totally not mandatory.   I like this approach, but I was having trouble get it to work.  How is it setting each var to true?

Comment: you are setting it in the array

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers and clarify why your example isn't working: when you initially set thisView, you are setting it to a string that is the same as the name of the variable you want to set; you are not making a reference to the variable you want to set. When you set it to true, you are just overwriting the string.

To refer to a variable by name directly, use the window object (`window['globalvariablename']`). If you can avoid referring to a variable directly through window though, and use a wrapper object, that would be better.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I knew I was overwriting the string, I just didn't know how to refer to it by name directly.  This is so helpful and thank you for clarifying.  I'm still new to jQuery and doing my best to use it more in my work.  Best Wishes!